# Get value from one Optional or another

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have two `java.util.Optional` instances and I want to get an `Optional` that either:

- Has the value of the first Optional, if it has a value.
- Has the value of the second Optional, if it has a value.
- Is empty of neither Optional has a value.

Is there a straight-forward way to do that, i.e. is there already some API to do that?

The following expressions will do that, but I have to mention the first optional twice:

```
firstOptional.isPresent() ? firstOptional : secondOptional
```

This is exactly what `com.google.common.base.Optional.or()` does, but that method is not present in Java 8's API.

---

The accepted answer by *aioobe* lists a few alternative approaches to overcome this omission of the `Optional` API right where such a value has to be computed (which answers my question). I've now opted to add a utility function to my codebase:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> or(Optional<T> a, Optional<T> b) {
    if (a.isPresent())
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

Comment: If you opt for using a utility function, I would recommend using a `Supplier<Optional<T>>` for the second parameter to support short-circuiting if the first is present.

Comment: @r0estir0bbe That would definitely be an option. I think both arguments were very cheap to calculate in the instance I was originally needing this. If it were after me, I'd be writing Haskell, where I wouldn't have to think about it. :)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### Java 9 and above:

```
firstOptional.or(() -> secondOptional);
```

### Java 8 and below

If you want to avoid mentioning `firstOptional` twice, you'd probably have to go with something like

```
firstOptional.map(Optional::of).orElse(secondOptional);
```

or

```
Optional.ofNullable(firstOptional.orElse(secondOptional.orElse(null)));
```

But the most readable variant is probably to simply do

```
Optional<...> opt = firstOptional.isPresent()  ? firstOptional
                  : secondOptional.isPresent() ? secondOptional
                  : Optional.empty();
```

---

If someone stumbles across this question but has a *list* of optionals, I'd suggest something like

```
Optional<...> opt = optionals.stream()
                             .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                             .findFirst()
                             .orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Comment: Won't your third example return an Optional<Optional<...>> since findFirst is operating on a Stream<Optional<...>>? You want stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(o -> o.get()).findFirst()

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning, that the Java 8 equivalent of the Java 9 `Optional.or` is `firstOptional.map(Optional::of).orElseGet(()->secondOptional)`. It only evaluates `secondOptional` if `firstOptional` is empty. Behaving in analogy to the logical `||`.

Answer (score 10):

*EDIT:* I totally thought you were using Guava's `Optional` originally. I've updated my answer to supply both Guava and Java 8 syntax for their respective `Optional` classes.

**Java 8 Optional**

You can shorten it up to this:

```
firstOptional.orElse(secondOptional.orElse(EMPTY_VALUE))
```

I'm not sure what you meant in your third bullet by "empty". If you meant null then this'll do the trick:

```
firstOptional.orElse(secondOptional.orElse(null))
```

`orElse()` is a method on `Optional` that will return the value if present, otherwise it will return the value you supplied as the argument to `orElse()`.

**Guava Optional**

You can shorten it up to this:

```
firstOptional.or(secondOptional.or(EMPTY_VALUE))
```

I'm not sure what you meant in your third bullet by "empty". If you meant null then this'll do the trick:

```
firstOptional.or(secondOptional.orNull())
```

`or()` is a method on `Optional` that will return the value if present, otherwise it will return the value you supplied as the argument to `or()`.

Comment: What type of optionals are you using? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Optional.html does not have this method

Comment: \*facepalm\* I mistakenly thought the OP was using Guava's `Optional` instead of Java 8's. I updated my answer to show the syntax for both.

Comment: By ''empty'' I mean `Optional.empty()`. I want to be able to use `ifPresent()` on the resulting optional.

Comment: For the Java 8 example, this will unwrap the Optional<T> so that you're just left with a T.

Answer (score 9):

I had a few encounters with a problem that might've been solved with JDK 9 `Optional::or` and couldn't because we use JDK 8. Finally I added a util class with this method:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Optional<T> firstPresent(final Supplier<Optional<T>>... optionals) {
    return Stream.of(optionals)
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

Now you can supply any number of optionals to this method and they'll be lazily evaluated like so:

```
    final Optional<String> username = OptionalUtil.firstPresent(
            () -> findNameInUserData(user.getBasicData()),
            () -> findNameInUserAddress(user.getAddress()),
            () -> findDefaultUsername());
```

Now, `findNameInUserAddress` will only be called if `findNameInUserData` returns empty. `findDefaultUsername` will only be called if both `findNameInUserData` and `findNameInUserAddress` return empty etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just (`Supplier` wrapper can be easily added):

```
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> Optional<T> firstPresent(Optional<T>... optionals) {
        return Stream.of(optionals)
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .findFirst();
    }
```

?

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is old, but why don't just use in this kind of cases something proven like Chain-of-responsibility pattern? It is made/designed for cases like yours. And as an additional benefit it's quite easy to add additional services to the list.

Here is a link that describes the Pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Comment: How does this apply to my question, which was about combining two `Optional<>` instances? Can you give an example how an implementation would look using this pattern?