# Guava Optional to Java 8 Optional with multiple choices

Tags: java-8, guava, option-type

This is a Guava Optional with multiple possible values.

```
long numberToUse = Long.parseLong(Optional
            .ofNullable(System.getenv(ENV_VAR))
            .or(Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(PROP_VAR)))
            .or("15"));
```

How can this converted to nice clean Java 8 syntax?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28818506/3920048

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use nested [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-):

```
long numberToUse = Long.parseLong(Optional
    .ofNullable(System.getenv(ENV_VAR))
    .orElse(
        Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(PROP_VAR))
                .orElse("15")));
```

Note that both in Guava and here the `System.getProperty(PROP_VAR)` branch is executed even if it's unnecessary. To make it lazy use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
long numberToUse = Long.parseLong(Optional
    .ofNullable(System.getenv(ENV_VAR))
    .orElseGet(
        () -> Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(PROP_VAR))
                .orElse("15")));
```

Java-9 adds [`.or`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-) method which makes the last sample simpler:

```
long numberToUse = Long.parseLong(Optional
        .ofNullable(System.getenv(ENV_VAR))
        .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(PROP_VAR)))
        .orElse("15"));
```

As @BoristheSpider suggests, you can also move `Long.parseLong` into optional pipeline:

```
long numberToUse = Optional
        .ofNullable(System.getenv(ENV_VAR))
        .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(PROP_VAR)))
        .map(Long::parseLong)
        .orElse(15L);
```

Finally it's possible to use Stream API instead (this works in Java-8 as well):

```
long numberToUse = Stream.of(System.getenv(ENV_VAR), System.getProperty(PROP_VAR))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().map(Long::parseLong).orElse(15L);
```