# Return first non empty list lazyily in Java 8

Tags: java, list, lambda, lazy-loading

I have N lists that return data from a Repository. I want to return the first non empty of these three lists (each one executes a different SQL to fetch data).

The catch is that I want to do this lazily, so that I don't need to execute a SQL on the database if I have already found an acceptable result. My code is (modified)

```
@Override
public List<Something> dataService(Data data) {

return firstNonEmptyList(repository.getDataWayOne(data.getParameter()), 
                         repository.getDataWayTwo(data.getParameter()),
                         repository.getDataWayThree(data.getParameter().getAcessoryParameter())
                         Collections.singletonList(repository.getDefaultData(data.getParameter()));

}

@SafeVarargs
private final List<Something> firstNonEmptyList(List<Something>... lists) {
for (List<Something> list : lists) {
  if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    return list;
  }
}

return null;

}
```

This works, but it isn't lazy. Any ideas?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it would be lazy if you wrap the list calls inside lambdas. In `firstNonEmptyList` you would evaluate each lambda until you find the one you want (i.e. the one that returns a non empty list). The non called lambdas would never execute the query. Anyway, the solution provided by shmosel does what I described and is way more elegant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make a stream of suppliers and evaluate them in encounter order until you find a result:

```
return Stream.<Supplier<List<Something>>>of(
            () -> repository.getDataWayOne(data.getParameter()),
            () -> repository.getDataWayTwo(data.getParameter()),
            () -> repository.getDataWayThree(data.getParameter().getAcessoryParameter()),
            () -> Collections.singletonList(repository.getDefaultData(data.getParameter()))
        )
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Each supplier defines how to access a result set, without actually attempting it until `map()` is executed. Since `filter()` and `map()` are [*stateless*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) operations, each supplier will be called and its result validated before the next one is attempted. If a non-empty result is found, the stream will terminate immediately, because `findFirst()` is [*short-circuiting*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

Comment: This is one of those Java 8 answers that make some people dizzy. If you only could explain it step by step and why is it lazy loading?

Comment: This is an excellent answer, the most Java8-ic way, pardon my French!

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I tried. Hopefully it's a little clearer now.

Comment: @shmosel would work with `...filter(List::isEmpty)`. For consistency, since you are mapping `Supplier::get`?

Comment: This is perfect and worked like a charm. Passed all tests and it's lazy. After the added explanation I understood it.

Answer (score 3):

If streams aren't your cup of tea, you can still use lambdas to achieve what you want with only some slight modifications to your original code.

```
public List<Something> dataService(Data data) {
    return firstNonEmptyList(
            () -> repository.getDataWayOne(data.getParameter()),
            () -> repository.getDataWayTwo(data.getParameter()),
            () -> repository.getDataWayThree(data.getParameter().getAcessoryParameter()),
            () -> Collections.singletonList(repository.getDefaultData(data.getParameter()))
        );
}

private final List<Something> firstNonEmptyList(Supplier<List<Something>>... listSuppliers) {
    for (Supplier<List<Something>> supplier : listSuppliers) {
        List<Something> list = supplier.get();
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            return list;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Coincidence, my last comment is exactly what you did here. It works (I guess), but the problem is that it hides the intention about laziness. A more functional style is welcomed in this case.

Comment: I actually think the opposite is true, the short-circuiting behavior of `firstNonEmptyList` is quite plain to see.  With streams, it's only obvious if you are quite familiar with the streams API, which not everyone is.  Plus Javadocs on the method could be used to help make it even more obvious.

Comment: This also worked and passed all my tests, including the lazy-loading. I appreciate that. I'm gonna use shmosel's one because it eliminates the auxiliary method.