# Java 8 Stream anyMatch() goes through the whole stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Given three functions like this:

```
private Optional<Integer> abc() {
    return Optional.of(6);
}


private Optional<Integer> def() {
    return Optional.of(3);
}


private Optional<Integer> ghi() {
    return Optional.of(9);
}
```

If I want to check if one of the three functions return something which is greater than 5 (of course wrapped in Optional), in a traditional imperative style I would do it like this:

```
if( abc().get() > 5 || def().get() > 5 || ghi().get() > 5) {
  ......// Do something
 }  // I am not doing get() without checking ifPresent() just for simplicity sake
```

This would only go into function `abc()` and skip `def()` and `ghi()`, because the first expression returns true. Which is a good optimization.
Now if I write the same in a functional style using Streams,

```
if( Stream.of(abc(), def(), ghi()).anyMatch(integer -> integer.get() > 5)) {
   .........
}
```

I thought the same would happen, i.e. only `abc()` will be called. But it calls all three functions. Isn't it redundant to check other two functions when there is `anyMatch()`?

It is same in the case of `noneMatch()`; the flow goes through whole Stream. I am just wondering: Isn't it really a bad thing to traverse the whole stream (especially if the stream has many values), even if the condition is met at the first element?

Comment: When you do `Stream.of(abc(), def(), ghi())` you are calling the 3 methods

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28818506/2711488

Comment: thanks @Holger. Waiting to use Java 9 :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `Stream#of` [happens before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) `Stream#anyMatch`, so all of the methods are called since they happens before `Stream#of`.

You can make `Stream#anyMatch` happens before actual method invocation by using `Supplier<Optional<Integer>>`, for example:

```
// Note: it just create Suppliers and actual method is called on demand 
Stream<Supplier<Optional<Integer>>> values=Stream.of(this::abc,this::def,this::ghi);

if(values.anyMatch(integer -> integer.get().get() > 5)) {
    .........
}
```

As @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner already mentioned, the `Optional` maybe empty   you can just use `Optional#orElse(0)` instead of `Optional#get`, or use `Opitional#filter(it -> it > 5).isPresent()`.

### Edit

To illustrate the short-circuiting terminal operations of `Stream`, you should use lambdas/method reference expressions since method call happens before `Stream#of`, for example:

```
Supplier<Optional<Integer>> failsOnMismatched = () -> { 
   throw new IllegalStateException(); 
};

// the instantiation of method reference happen before `Stream#of`,
// but the linked method is called on demand.
//                 v 
if(Stream.of(this::abc, failsOnMismatched).anyMatch(it -> it.get().orElse(0) > 5)){
  //reached
}

//it is failed since the value of def() <= 5 ---v
if(Stream.of(this::def, failsOnMismatched).anyMatch(it -> it.get().orElse(0) > 5)){
  //unreachable
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Java 9 or higher, you could chain the optionals, applying [`Optional.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), [`Optional.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [`Optional.ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
abc().filter(n -> n > 5)
    .or(() -> def().filter(n -> n > 5))
    .or(() -> ghi().filter(n -> n > 5))
    .ifPresent(n -> {
        // do domething
    });
```

Note that this solution is complete, i.e. you don't need to check if any value is present, as this is already done by `Optional.filter`, `Optional.or` and `Optional.ifPresent`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) may not evaluated for all specific elements in predicate. But, at the same `of` also expects argument(s), which means they will be evaluated first.

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided
>   predicate. ***May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not
>   necessary for determining the result***. If the stream is empty then
>   false is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.