# How can I map Optional to another Optional if not present?

Tags: java, option-type

I have this Java 8 code:

```
public Optional<User> getUser(String id) {
    Optional<User> userFromCache = cache.getUser(id);
    if (userFromCache.isPresent()) {
        return userFromCache;
    }
    return repository.getUser(id);
}
```

It works fine but I'm wondering how can I chain the call to not to use `if`. I have tried with `orElseGet` but it doesn't allow to return another `Optional<User>` but a `User`.

I want something like this:

```
Optional<User> userFromCache = cache.getUser(id)
    .orElseGet(() -> repository.getUser(id));
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818506/optional-orelse-optional-in-java. There are answers for both JDK 8 and 9. See the answer by @Misha, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821352.

Comment: This really should be closed as a duplicate but I have no more flags .^.

Comment: @Druckles Hmm, agreed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Java 9, there is [`Optional.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)). It accepts a supplier for another `Optional`.

```
return cache.getUser(id).or(() -> repository.getUser(id));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Unfortunately I'm using Java 8 =(

Comment: @Héctor then your approach is good enough and probably is the best way possible in jdk8

Answer (score 6):

You can create an optional based on a nullable value from other optionals:

```
public Optional<User> getUser(String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(
        cache.getUser(id).orElseGet(
            () -> repository.getUser(id).orElse(null)
        )
    );
}
```

But your current solution is clearly more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use ?:

```
return (userFromCache.isPresent()) ? userFromCache : repository.getUser(id);
```

It's obviously an if in disguise but so is any other solution.