# Stream till value found - optional

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I want to terminate execution of stream when found first value. However, when I run code below it shows up that two methods are called even if value is present from *first* method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Optional<String> s = Stream.of(first(), second())
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .findFirst()
                .flatMap(Function.identity());

        System.out.println(s.get());
    }

    private static Optional<String> first() {
        System.out.println("first");
        return Optional.of("someValue");
    }

    private static Optional<String> second() {
        System.out.println("second");
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

I checked in docs that:

1. isPresent

> Return {@code true} if there is a value present, otherwise {@code
>   false}.

2. findFirst()

> Returns an {@link Optional} describing the first element of this
>   stream, or an empty {@code Optional} if the stream is empty.  If the
>   stream has no encounter order, then any element may be returned.

So the first condition it met, and the second seems to be also fulfilled cause it returns:

```
first
second
someValue
```

How to quit execution if first value present, and not execute *second* method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to quit execution if first value present, and not execute second method?

`Stream#findFirst` is a short-circuiting terminal operation. However, the methods are being invoked when you call `Stream.of(first(), second())`. This can be proven with the following snippet:

```
Optional<String> s = Stream.of(first(), second())
                           .peek($ -> System.out.println("Hello World!"))
                           .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                           .findFirst()
                           .flatMap(Function.identity());

System.out.println(s.get());
```

Output:

```
first
second
Hello World!
someValue
```

---

To prevent `first()` and `second()` from executing when calling `Stream#of`, one solution would be to wrap them in a `Supplier<Optional<String>>`:

```
Stream<Supplier<Optional<String>>> stream = Stream.of(Test::first, Test::second);

Optional<String> s = stream.map(Supplier::get)
                           .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                           .findFirst()
                           .flatMap(Function.identity());

System.out.println(s.get());
```

Output:

```
first
someValue
```

Comment: `Stream<Supplier<Optional<String>>> supplierStream = Stream.of(Test::first, Test::second);
        Optional<String> s = supplierStream...` can help readability there.

Comment: Good point, I'm not a big fan of the cast as well. I'll change it :)

Comment: Instead of `.findFirst() .flatMap(Function.identity())` you can also use `.findFirst() .orElse(Optional.empty())` or `.map(Optional::get) .findFirst()`. Seems to be a [recurring question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28833677/2711488), but finding it via Stackoverflow’s search function is indeed really hard…

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that `findFirst` is not short-circuiting, but that `Stream.of(first(), second())` causes immediate (not delayed) execution of `first()` and `second`. It's essentially evaluated as any ordinary expression.

In other words, even if your main method is just

```
final public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Stream.of(first(), second());
}
```

It would still execute `first()` and `second()` immediately.