# OptionalInt - Creating Nested orElse() branch

Tags: java, option-type

Is there a concise pipeline-like pattern for Java's optional when having something like `if - else if - else`-like structures?

For example, we have two functions returning `OptionalInt`s, and we want to use the result of `f`, if present, otherwise the result of `g`, if present, and otherwise `0`:

```
OptionalInt f(...) {
    return ...
}

OptionalInt g(...) {
    return ...
}


int res = f(...).orElse(g(...).orElse(0));
```

Is there a more pipline-like structure of this pattern, e.g. (*pseudocode*)

```
int res = f(...)
    .orElseTry(g(...))
    .otherwise(0);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional orElse Optional in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818506/optional-orelse-optional-in-java) Probably not, though: the answers there work with `Optional`, not with `OptionalInt`.

Comment: As a complete aside, if the call to `g()` is costly, you may prefer `f().orElseGet(() -> g().orElse(0))`. It has nothing to do with solving the issue you asked about.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you. The link you provided is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `OptionalInt` you can use [`orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.IntSupplier)) (credits to *@Ole V.V.* since he has pointed it out in the comments earlier):

```
int res = f().orElseGet(() -> g().orElse(0));
```

In case if there are more than two sources for producing result, you can use the following approach:

```
int res = Stream.<Supplier<OptionalInt>>of(
        () -> f(),
        () -> g(),
        ...                           // other sources for producing the optional result    
    )                                 // Stream<Supplier<OptionalInt>>
    .map(Supplier::get)
    .filter(OptionalInt::isPresent)  // Stream<OptionalInt>>
    .mapToInt(OptionalInt::getAsInt) // IntStream
    .findFirst()                     // OptionalInt
    .orElse(0);
```

Comment: Thank you, the second code snipped looks good so far. I was indeed looking for a solution where I can try multiple sources in sequence and take the first producer's result that's not null.