# What's the most elegant way to combine optionals?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Optional<Foo> firstChoice = firstChoice();
Optional<Foo> secondChoice = secondChoice();
return Optional.ofNullable(firstChoice.orElse(secondChoice.orElse(null)));
```

This strikes me as both hideous and wasteful. If firstChoice is present I am needlessly computing secondChoice.

There's also a more efficient version:

```
Optional<Foo> firstChoice = firstChoice();
if(firstChoice.isPresent()) {
 return firstChoice;
} else {
 return secondChoice();
}
```

Here I can't chain some mapping function to the end without either duplicating the mapper or declaring another local variable. All of this makes the code more complicated than the actual problem being solved.

I'd much rather be writing this:

```
return firstChoice().alternatively(secondChoice());
```

However Optional::alternatively obviously doesn't exist. Now what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from one Optional or another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599996/get-value-from-one-optional-or-another)

Comment: ... when confronted with the problem of null ... now we have two problems.

Comment: Btw, Paul Sandoz just published a [changeset](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~psandoz/jdk9/JDK-8080418-optional-or/webrev/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java.udiff.html) for review which introduces `Optional.or()` method, which does exactly what you want: `firstChoice().or(this::secondChoice)`. More info at [JDK-8080418](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080418). In Java-9 times we'll be happy!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
firstChoice().map(Optional::of)
             .orElseGet(this::secondChoice);
```

The map method gives you an `Optional<Optional<Foo>>`. Then, the `orElseGet` method flattens this back to an `Optional<Foo>`. The `secondChoice` method will only be evaluated if `firstChoice()` returns the empty optional.

Comment: Note: Java 9 introduces the `Optional::or` method. This could therefore be written `firstChoice().or(this::secondChoice)` in Java 9.

Comment: This only works with Java8 if `this::secondChoice` returns a `Supplier` rather than `Optional` - the example from the OP does not.

Comment: @exception `this::secondChoice` _is_ a `Supplier`. It is a method reference.

Comment: In the OP's example, that method returns Optional, which is not a Supplier - and I was pointing out that for Java8 it is different.

Comment: @exception `secondChoice()` returns an `Optional`. `this::secondChoice` is a method reference of type `Supplier<Optional<Foo>>`. If you call the method reference, you get the `Optional`. The example in the answer works for Java 8 and onward.

Comment: @martstran Argh, overlooked that detail. My bad.

Comment: doesn't work with static methods

Comment: @caduceus It does. Just use `.orElseGet(MyClass::secondChoice);`

Answer (score 7):

Java 9 added the [`Optional.or​(supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-) method for this sort of situation.

```java
return firstChoice().or(this::secondChoice);
```

Given methods `firstChoice()` and `secondChoice()` which each return `Optional<Foo>`, the above one-liner uses `Optional.or` to achieve the desired result.

As desired, this approach only computes `secondChoice` when `firstChoice` is empty.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this:

```
Optional<String> finalChoice = Optional.ofNullable(firstChoice()
    .orElseGet(() -> secondChoice()
    .orElseGet(() -> null)));
```

From: [Chaining Optionals in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514704/chaining-optionals-in-java-8)

Comment: Your last line of the three can be simplified to: `.orElse(null)));`

Comment: not sure if it is a good idea to return null in Optional since they were introduced to avoid using nulls. I would rather return  Optional.empty()

Answer (score 5):

You can simply replace that with,

```
Optional<Foo> firstChoice = firstChoice();
return firstChoice.isPresent()? firstChoice : secondChoice();
```

The above code won't call unless *firstChoice.isPresent()* is false.

But you have to be prepare to call both functions to get the desired output. There is no other way to escape the checking.

- Best case is First choice returning true.
- Worst case will be First choice returning false, hence another method
  call for second choice.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the generalization of @marstran solution for any number of optionals:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Optional<T> selectOptional(Supplier<Optional<T>>... optionals) {
    return Arrays.stream(optionals)
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> () -> s1.get().map(Optional::of).orElseGet(s2))
            .orElse(Optional::empty).get();
}
```

Test:

```
public static Optional<String> first() {
    System.out.println("foo called");
    return Optional.empty();
}

public static Optional<String> second() {
    System.out.println("bar called");
    return Optional.of("bar");
}

public static Optional<String> third() {
    System.out.println("baz called");
    return Optional.of("baz");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(selectOptional(() -> first(), () -> second(), () -> third()));
}
```

Output:

```
foo called
bar called
Optional[bar]
```

Answer (score 3):

I was frustrated enough by the fact that this wasn't supported in java 8, that I switched back to guava's optionals which have [`or`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or(com.google.common.base.Optional)):

```
public abstract Optional<T> or(Optional<? extends T> secondChoice)
```

> Returns this Optional if it has a value present; secondChoice otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy computations and arbitrary number of `Optional` elements

```
Stream.<Supplier<Optional<Foo>>>of(
        this::firstChoice,
        this::secondChoice
).map(
        Supplier::get
).filter(
        Optional::isPresent
).findFirst(
).orElseGet(
    Optional::empty
);
```

Answer (score 0):

with java 11 you can simply do `firstChoice().or(this::secondChoice)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way which works for arbitrary number of `Optional`'s based in a stream API:

```
return Arrays.asList(firstChoice, secondChoice).stream()
  .filter(Optional::isPresent)
  .map(Optional::get)
  .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

It's not the shortest one. But more plain and understandable.

Another way is to use `firstNonNull()` from Guava of commons-lang if you are already using one of those libraries:

```
firstNonNull(firstChoice.orElse(null), secondChoice.orElse(null));
```

Comment: I find this a lot less understandable than the `if` solution in the question, btw.

Comment: Well, I agree if the only thing you have is 2 `Optional`s. This is why I stated that this way works for _arbitrary number_ of `Optional`s.

Comment: The problem of your solution is that it's not short-circuiting: you have to evaluate all the choices which is exactly what the OP tries to avoid. In OPs code `firstChoice()` and `secondChoice()` are actually methods and you cannot simply modify your solution to omit calling the second one if the first produced non-empty optional.

Comment: What do you mean? `findFirst()` defined as a short-circuting operation in documentation. You can easily check that `Optional.get()` and `Optional.isPresent()` methods called only once using debugger.