# Optional in orElse-Branch throws Exception

Tags: java, exception, java-8, option-type

So I'm working with Optionals and came across a strange behaviour. I want to know if this is really an intendet "feature" or something...odd...

Here is the given example:
I've got a method with an Optional in whose orElse I want to evaluate an other optional. If the other Optional is not present, I'll raise an IllegalArgumentException:

```
firstOptionalVar.orElse(secondOptionalVar.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new));
```

Now if the `secondOptionalVar` is an empty Optional, it will raise an IllegalArgumentException, even if the `firstOptionalVar` is Present. This doesn't seem right to me. I would expect it to just raise an IllegalArgumentException if the `firstOptionalVar` would not be present.

It's not a big deal to get arround this behavior with java7-methods like:

```
firstOptionalVar.isPresent() ? firstOptionalVar.get() : secondOptionalVar.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour before? Is this really the way optionals should behave?

Comment: `flatMap` does the opposite unfortunately.

Comment: The anwer to the exception can be found in the linked question or the answers you got. Note that the "or" operation you want to perform will be available on Java 9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599996/get-value-from-one-optional-or-another

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution of @resueman will work for me, but it's good to know how java9 will handle this case :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. `orElse` expects an argument of type `T` (whatever the generic type of the `Optional` is. `orElseThrow` returns a `T`, so it needs to be evaluated first, in order to pass the parameter into `orElse`.

What you want is `orElseGet`, which takes a `Supplier<T>`. That will delay execution of the `orElseThrow` until after `firstOptionalVar` has already been checked.

So your code should look like this:

```
firstOptionalVar.orElseGet(() -> secondOptionalVar.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new));
```

That will turn the `orElseThrow` section into a lambda, and only evaluate it if it's needed (ie. when `firstOptionalVar` doesn't have a value to get).

Comment: Nice one. This is the solution I've been trying to figure out. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

At the heart of everything, you're still only calling Java methods, and therefore the standard Java order of evaluation applies.

Specifically: `secondOptionalVar.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)` has to be evaluated **before** the call to `firstOptionalVar.orElse()`, as it provides the argument of `firstOptionalVar.orElse()`.

I can't see any easy way of resolving this with standard methods of `Optional`, you can always build a stream out of the two optionals and get the first element or else throw an exception, but it seems a bit convoluted.